# Update Table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Got stuck and need some help, This should be relatively simple but it's been my bane for a few weeks now and am on the verg of giving up!
The problem is my user registration form for a social network I'm building all I want to do is replace a space with a + when the user enters their address into the database.
I have a page called activation.php that gets called into action when the user activates thie email address and I have this code block on the page...

```
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET email_activated='1' WHERE id='$id' AND password='$hashpass'"); 
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET firstname = REPLACE(firstname, ' ', '+'");
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET lastname = REPLACE(lastname, ' ', '+'");
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET housenumber = REPLACE(housenumber, ' ', '+'");
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET addressone = REPLACE(addressone, ' ', '+'");
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET addresstwo = REPLACE(addresstwo, ' ', '+'");
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET county = REPLACE(county, ' ', '+'");
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET city = REPLACE(city, ' ', '+'");
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET country = REPLACE(country, ' ', '+'");
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET postcode = REPLACE(postcode, ' ', '+'");
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET phone = REPLACE(phone, ' ', '+'");
   $sql_doublecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMembers WHERE id='$id' AND password='$hashpass' AND email_activated='1'"); 
   $doublecheck = mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck);
```

But of course it's not updating the spaces with a +,  Am I missing a trick somewhere or is this destined to fail!
Of course it goes without saying that I will thank you all in advance!
Regards
-P

Comment: why use sql to replace? can't you use php `preg_replace` for doing this? and btw if a user register's it should have `INSERT` query rather than an `UPDATE` query, moreover, that looks messy to me

Comment: your query seems fine. [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/907da/1).

Comment: It looks like you're trying to encode URI entities? I'm sure there's a better function than just replacing spaces with +es.

Comment: Furthermore, are you sure you want to be updating ALL rows every time any user activates their address?

Comment: I see you are quite new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the `REPLACE()` calls have closing parentheses.

```
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET email_activated='1' WHERE id='$id' AND password='$hashpass'"); 
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET firstname = REPLACE(firstname, ' ', '+')");
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET lastname = REPLACE(lastname, ' ', '+')");
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET housenumber = REPLACE(housenumber, ' ', '+')");
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET addressone = REPLACE(addressone, ' ', '+')");
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET addresstwo = REPLACE(addresstwo, ' ', '+')");
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET county = REPLACE(county, ' ', '+')");
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET city = REPLACE(city, ' ', '+')");
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET country = REPLACE(country, ' ', '+')");
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET postcode = REPLACE(postcode, ' ', '+')");
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET phone = REPLACE(phone, ' ', '+')");
 $sql_doublecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMembers WHERE id='$id' AND password='$hashpass' AND email_activated='1'"); 
 $doublecheck = mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck);
```

Comment: Arr, could that be it, simple! 3 weeks of work trying to figure that out! many thanks Bart! will change them all now and test! will get back if fails

Comment: Error messages can be very helpful in cases like this. ;).

Answer (score 1):

Few problems

As pointed by Bart Friederichs, you're missing close parentheses.

Most of your UPDATE statement will update ALL your database entries (queries without a WHERE statement)

You create one query per field to update...

```
UPDATE myMembers SET 
   email_activated='1',
   firstname = REPLACE(firstname, ' ', '+'),
   lastname = REPLACE(lastname, ' ', '+'),
   housenumber = REPLACE(housenumber, ' ', '+')
   --etc
WHERE 
   id='$id' AND password='$hashpass'
```